# Error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'token') react query

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-query

**Explanation:**
I'm trying to fetch data from my backend using react query, so i have user context it's dispatched to get a token from the local storage once every time when the app render so i can use that user context for my app.

**Problem:**
I tried to fetch the data using the useQuery hook depending on the user but it gives me "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'token')" **after fetching the data**

**Code:**

```
function MyProfile (){

    const {user} = useAuthContext()
    
    const getInfo = async ()=>{

        
        const postsData = await (await fetch(`/hr/myProfile`,{
          method:"POST",
          headers:{'Authorization':`Bearer ${await user.token}`,'Content-type': 'application/json'},
          body:JSON.stringify(user)
        })).json()
        
        return postsData

      }
     
  const {data,status, isLoading} = useQuery(['user',user],getInfo)
```

So i tried making a condition to make sure that the user context dispatched and then fetch the data,i got another error "Query data cannot be undefined. Please make sure to return a value other than undefined from your query function. Affected query key: ["user"]"

looks like the dispatch taking time to update the 'user' value

**I know i can take the user token from the local storage directly but i want to know how can i take it from the user context**

**Code:**

```
function MyProfile (){

    const {user} = useAuthContext()
    
    const getInfo = async ()=>{

        if(user){

          const postsData = await (await fetch(`/hr/myProfile`,{
            method:"POST",
            headers:{'Authorization':`Bearer ${await user.token}`,'Content-type': 'application/json'},
            body:JSON.stringify(user)
          })).json()
          
          return postsData

        }
       
      }
   
  const {data,status, isLoading} = useQuery(['user'],getInfo)
```

**authContext:**
**Code:**

```
export const AuthContext = createContext()

//reducer for state of user 
export const authReducer = (state,action)=>{

        switch(action.type){

            case 'LOGIN': 
                return {user: action.payload}

            case 'LOGOUT':
                return {user:null}
            default: 
                return state

        }

}



export const AuthContextProvider = ({children})=>{

        const [state,dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer,{user:null})
        

        //useEffect to get the token every time when the user join the web page
        useEffect(()=>{

            const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) 

            if(user){

                dispatch({type:'LOGIN',payload:user})
                
            }
            
        },[])
```

**useAuthContext hook:**
**Code**:

```
import {AuthContext} from '../context/HR-context/authContext'
import { useContext } from 'react'

export const useAuthContext = ()=>{
//consoming context hook
    const context = useContext(AuthContext)

    if(!context){

        throw Error('useAuthContext must be use inside  AuthContextProvider')

    }

    return context
```

**Resolve Code:**
so after hours of trying i used the useRef hook, i put the useQuery enabled to false so its cant render or fetch the data after that, i put a condition to check if there is a user and i updated my useQuery enabled to true using useRef state

```
 const {user}= useAuthContext()
    const state = useRef(false)
    if(user){
        state.current = true
    }
    
    const getInfo = async ()=>{

        //const user =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
        
        if(state.current === true){

            const postsData = await (await fetch(`/hr/myProfile`,{
                method:"POST",
                headers:{'Authorization':`Bearer ${await user.token}`,'Content-type': 'application/json'},
                body:JSON.stringify(user)
              })).json()
              
              return postsData
    
          }
        }
            
          
          
  const {data,status} = useQuery(['user'],getInfo,{enabled:state.current})
```

Comment: You need to show useAuthContext code.

Comment: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/dependent-queries

You possibly want to try this first of all add something like `enabled: !!user` to your useQuery

Comment: @morganney
 I update the code at the top with the details

Comment: @delis
i tried it before, nothing happened my status freeze on loading and not fetching